# Как правильно сделать итерацию в шаблоне Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jinja2

В вёрстке частенько встречаются шаблоны плитки, где простой итерацией, на сколько я понимаю, её не построить.
Пример 1:

```html
<section>
    <div class="blog">
        <article class="first">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="first">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="first">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="two">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="two">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="first">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="first">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
    <article class="first">
            <div class="article-title">
                <h3>Title Article</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article-description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque. </p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

Т.е. например 4 и 5 элемент имееют совершенно другой класс. Я так понимаю, в этом случае нужно использовать loop и сравнивать шаг итерации менять класс??? А что если такая плитка раза в два или три больше, то в это случае как правильно?

Пример 2:
Всё тоже самое, но если есть строки

```
<section>
    <div class="blog">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="two">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <article class="two">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Ну и пример 3, тут я честно вообще не особо могу догнать, если есть разрыв в виде вставки блока:

```
<section>
    <div class="blog">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="two">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
</div>
<section>
    <div class="blog">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="two">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

В этом случае как? Вызывать итерацию дважды и тоже по loop отсекать?

Answer (score 1):

```
<section>
    <div class="blog">
        <div class="row">


             {% for item in yourList %}


            <article class="first">
                <div class="article-title">
                    <h3>Title Article</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="article-description">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed augue iaculis odio lobortis fermentum. Fusce elit erat, cursus vel iaculis sollicitudin, dignissim fringilla est. Maecenas consequat nisi et est blandit lobortis. Maecenas posuere euismod lorem sit amet commodo. Curabitur auctor non elit ornare lacinia. Mauris ac justo convallis orci lobortis interdum et at sapien. Fusce mattis accumsan dui, vel congue turpis sollicitudin at. Nunc arcu ante, lacinia vel mauris at, malesuada laoreet sem. Phasellus massa ex, facilisis at augue ac, finibus ultrices ligula. Nunc malesuada metus vitae lacus tristique tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sit amet tortor nec sapien euismod rhoncus. Fusce eget venenatis sapien. Donec eu efficitur felis. Proin vel ante pellentesque, porta dui dapibus, sodales neque.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

А во views.py в соответствующей функции нужно сделать yourList. Таким образом подставляй информацию в теги которую хочешь изменить. Например если хочешь изменить класс где-то пишешь `class={{item.myClass}`

Comment: Это я понял, это прямая итерация получается, с этим проблем нет. А если каждые четыре элемента отделяются <div class="row">?

Comment: Тогда сделай список где будет три элемента пустых, а четвертый `<div class="row">`. Например `['', '', '',  '<div class="row">'] `

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста. Список этот где создавать?